# Code Vision AVR for Ubuntu

Tags: 11.10

IS there any ways that I can use the Code Vision AVR Compiler? Please answer my question I gonna make  a robot, So I need a useful compiler for my Ubuntu.We are usually work on Atmel micro controllers, As you know these micro controllers only program by DAP300 programmers & AVR compilers. If you have nice answer contact me with my Email: ariantalkoo@gmail.com      .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is several compilers in Ubuntu for avr, like gcc-avr or sdcc. I think that could solve your issues.